# 10 bit ADC Value to Voltage measurement

Tags: atmega, adc

I am trying to do ADC using ATMEGA8 and receiving the ADC value from the potentiometer. As it is 10 Bit ADC the highest value i can receive is 1024.
Now i want to convert this value to actual voltage and view it on terminal using serial. My reference voltage is 5V.

this is what i am doing

```
#define REF_ADC_Volt    5000
#define ADC_Div_Factor  1023

//init ADC
void Init_ADC()
{
    ADMUX  |= (1<<REFS0);                   //Reference voltage set at AREF pin
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);                //Enable ADC
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS0) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS2);    //set prescale by 128 div factor
}
//Read ADC
uint16_t Read_ADC(uint8_t ch)
{
    ch = ch & 0x07;
    ADMUX |= ch;                        //Setting ADC Channel
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);                //ADC start conversion 
    while (! (ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)) );    //Wait till conversion is over
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIF);                //Clear ADC Flag    
    return(ADCW);                       //Return ADC value 10 bit
}

int main(void)
{
    _delay_ms(2000);
    Init_ADC();
    USART_Init(103);
    double ADC_Val,Res_ADC_Val;
    char *number_string="00000";

    USART_Transmit_String("ACS712 Current Sensor ADC Value: \r\n");
    while (1) 
    {
        ADC_Val = Read_ADC(0);

        Res_ADC_Val = ((REF_ADC_Volt / ADC_Div_Factor) * ADC_Val)/1000;
        dtostrf(Res_ADC_Val,1,2,number_string);
        USART_Transmit_String(number_string);
        itoa(ADC_Val,number_string,10);
        USART_Transmit(' ');
        USART_Transmit_String(number_string);
        USART_Transmit_String("\r\n");

        ClearBuffer(number_string);
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is after conversion the highest voltage i am getting is 4.09V at ADC value of 1023. But it should be 5V right??

According to this calculation

```
Res_ADC_Val = ((REF_ADC_Volt / ADC_Div_Factor) * ADC_Val)/1000;
```

where

```
REF_ADC_Volt  = 5000mV
ADC_Div_Factor = 1023
ADC_Val = 1023
```

I am totally confused as when i use my calculator its 5V  only but I'm getting 4.09. Why? and How to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **REF_ADC_Volt** and **ADC_Div_Factor** are two **integer** literals.

Hence, the first division produces an **integer** result (most likely 4).

Then, you multiply the result of this division (4) by ADC_Val.

This means 4 * 1023 = 4.092.

You should promote your literals to floating point:

```
#define REF_ADC_Volt    5000.0
#define ADC_Div_Factor  1023.0
```

or re-arrange the expression to allow implicit casting to work, eg:

```
Res_ADC_Val = REF_ADC_Volt * ADC_Val / ADC_Div_Factor / 1000.0;
```

**EDIT #1:**

**Optimization tip**

As pointed out in other answers, the implementation above is sub optimal. Optimization was not the topic of the answer, but it is always interesting to discuss such things.

Please note that the solutions proposed in the other answers are **not** the most efficent either.

In fact, there is **no need** to perform all those divisions, since they all involve **constant** values.

You can define **one constant** as your scalar and perform just **one** multiplication each time:

```
#define ADC_TO_VOLT 0.00488758553275 // (5000.0 / 1023.0) / 1000.0


Res_ADC_Val = ADC_Val * ADC_TO_VOLT;
```

Moreover, there may be no need to use double values. I believe single precision values (float) should suffice, but that depends on your application and it's hard to judge from your minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is completely correct, but if code execution time and optimisation is important to you, you can do much of the calculation in int instead of double.

```
#define REF_ADC_mVolt  = 5000
#define ADC_Div_Factor = 1023

double Res_ADC_Val;
uint16_t ADC_Val; //notice the uint16_t instead double

ADC_Val = Read_ADC(0);

Res_ADC_Val = (((uint32_t)REF_ADC_mVolt * ADC_Val)/ ADC_Div_Factor )/(double)1000.0;
```

Now there is only one slow "double" division. Notice the typecast to `uint32_t` to avoid overflow. And notice `(double)1000.0` where the `.0` alone would cast only to float instead double.